# Using magic methods on Symfony for routing

Tags: symfony, magic-methods

on Symfony 4, I'm trying to have a __call method for the DefaultController which will be able to handle all calls to /api/{model}, example:

```
#config/routes.yml
get:
    path: /api/{model}/
    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\DefaultController::get' }
```

"get" method is not defined on DefaultController, but I have the __call() method that will handle it.

I have read about the [PropertyAccessor Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) that allows you to call these non existing methods from other parts of the php code, but not when they are used on the routes.yml file.

On Laravel it is working fine, the route points to DefaultController@get and the __call method on the controller handles it properly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you are basically using __call to pretend the controller has a method called get?  Why?  Why not just add a method called get?  In any event, the answer below is correct.  Symfony does a lot of processing on controller methods.  This approach is just not going to work.

Comment: I'm doing it in this way because all create, read, update and delete methods of the controller will do the same, gather request params and send them to their respective Command. So, in order to not duplicate code, I had the intention of using the same function (__call), in the same way I am doing in the Laravel code (I am porting it from Laravel to Symfony). If I have to do it in another way, I will do as @julien says because it seems the more reasonable way

Comment: The answer below is certainly reasonable.  And if you are porting existing code then knowing you have common functionality between say read and update is okay though I don't really understand how.  For CRUD stuff you might take a look at [Param Converters](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) and [request filters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html).  They may or may not be applicable to your particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this does not work, but probably because Symfony do some code introspection if your method exists.

I do not think that you should do that by the way for two reasons:

- Using `__call` is slower than having a proper function definition, and you know that you function should be defined as you define it in your routing
- Developpers will need more reflection to understand where the code is located, and junior developpers won't even understand the logic

If you really need a "catch all" function, you may call it from your `getAction` function:

```
class SomeController
{
    public function get() {
        return $this->catchAll(__METHOD__);
    }

    public function catchAll($method) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll implement it this way, it's the more reasonable one. Thanks!